# Sending confirmation email with SendGrid on Rails - am I saving user data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

The boilerplate code from the [Rails tutorial of SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html) looks like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # Create the user from params
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      # Deliver the signup email
      UserNotifier.send_signup_email(@user).deliver
      redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User created')
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

but for me the like `redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User created')` was causing problems- I guess because my own database was not set up in that way.

Then what I did was replace it by `render :new unless @user.save`, because that's what my old create method looked like, i.e. it looked like this:

```
# def create
#   @user = User.new(user_params)
#   render :new unless @user.save
# end
```

Now my function looks like so:

```
def create
  # Create the user from params
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    # Deliver the signup email
    UserNotifierMailer.send_signup_email(@user).deliver
    # redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User created')
    render :new unless @user.save
  else
    # render :action => 'new'
    render :new unless @user.save
    # is putting "render :new unless @user.save" detrimental? does it
    # actually solve the problem of saving that user?
  end
end
```

Is that reasonable? I mean - admittedly it's kind of hacky - is it bad though?

Comment: You're doing the thing where you put your questions in your code comments. Generally though, saving twice in a method is not good practice. Figure out your "causing problems- I guess because..." thing.

Comment: could you please be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `redirect` after `create` object:

```
def create
  # Create the user from params
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    # Deliver the signup email
    UserNotifierMailer.send_signup_email(@user).deliver
    redirect_to new_user_path # or another path what you wish
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

if you use `render` you render only view, if `redirect_to` - you go to view through action

Comment: but actually what I'm really gunning for is the ability to send a confirmation link- so that the user is only added to the db if they click that link- you know what I mean? can I do that using sendgrid?

Comment: you can use any email service, in controller it doesn't matter. Mailer will use that mail-service what you setted up.

Comment: 'redirect_to new_user_path # or another path what you wish' that makes an error- :/ how can I find out what another path would be called- maybe index? or the login screen- would it be in the routes file?

Comment: you can see all you pathes from console `rake routes`, than choose what you need

Comment: this is a 2 part question: (a) can I do `redirect_to 'welcome#index'`? (b) so then- I can use sendgrid or any email service to send that confirmation link? so that a user won't get entered into my db unless they click some special link?

Comment: (a) use route helpers, don't find troubles, (b) you have to create user in any case, if user fill out form without mistakes. After that user just have to follow confirmation link, and you - mark him as confirmed